# backbone marionette requirejs childviewcontainer, views is undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, revolution-slider

I'm building a web app with requirejs, backbone, marionette and plugins like ervolution-slider, waypoints, smothscroll. I'm having many problems with load dependencies. I need to refresh so many times so that page loads properly. I got errors like below the first time I load the page, after many refresh my page loads successful. Also, after I go to aboutus and then home, I got undefined errors but with other views. In fact, sometimes the header or footer are not able to load.

```
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChildViewContainer' of undefined(…)Module.check @ require.js:900
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Application' of undefined(…)Module.check @ require.js:900
require.js:900 ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined(…)Module.check @ require.js:900
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutView' of undefined(…)Module.check @ require.js:900
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot set property 'About' of undefined(…)Module.check @ require.js:900
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ItemView' of undefined(…)
```

Basically, my app have a header, footer, home page and aboutus page. Header and Footer are modules loaded in main file. Home and aboutus load through routers.

main.js

```
 require.config({
map: {
    '*': {
        'css': 'plugins/require-css/css'
    }
},
paths: {
    'plugins': '../plugins',
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery-2.1.4',
    'jquery.browser': '../plugins/jquery.browser',
    'jquery.video': '../plugins/vide/jquery.vide.min',
    'waypoints': '../plugins/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min',
    'backbone': '../lib/backbone',
    'marionette': '../lib/backbone.marionette',
    'backbone.subroute': '../lib/backbone.subroute',
    'text': '../lib/text',
    'tpl': '../lib/tpl',
    'underscore': '../lib/underscore',
    'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap',
    'modernizr': '../lib/modernizr-2.8.3',
    'themepunch.tools': '../plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min',
    'themepunch.rev': '../plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution',
    'smoothscroll': '../plugins/SmoothScroll',
    //our modules
    'core':'core',
    'header': 'modules/header',
    'footer': 'modules/footer',
    'home': 'modules/home',
    'aboutus': 'modules/aboutus',
},
shim: {
    'marionette': {
        deps: ['backbone'],
        exports: 'Marionette'
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
    },
    'tpl': {
        deps: ['text']
    },
    'smoothscroll': {
        deps: ['jquery.browser']
    },
    'themepunch.tools': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'themepunch.rev': {
        deps: ['themepunch.tools']
    },
    'jquery.browser': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'waypoints': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquery.video': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
});
require([
   "app", "routes/application.router",
   "header/header.module",
   "footer/footer.module",
   "home/home.module",
   "aboutus/aboutus.module",
   "bootstrap"],
function (GB, AppRouter) {
    GB.routers = new AppRouter();
    GB.start();
});
```

app.js:

```
define([
"marionette",
"core/GB.ini",
"modernizr",
"themepunch.rev",
"smoothscroll",
"jquery.video"
],
function (Marionette, AppIni) {
    var GB = new Marionette.Application();

    GB.navigate = function (route, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        GB.routers.navigate(route, options);
    };

    GB.getCurrentRoute = function () {
        return Backbone.history.fragment
    };

    GB.on("before:start", function () {
        var RegionContainer = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
            el: "#app-container",

            regions: {
                header: "#header-wrapper",
                main: "#main-region",
                footer: "#footer-region",
                dialog: "#dialog-region"
            }
        });

        GB.regions = new RegionContainer();

    });

    GB.on("start", function () {
        AppIni.start();
        Backbone.history.start();
        if (GB.getCurrentRoute() === "")
            GB.navigate("home", { trigger: true });
    });

    return GB;
});
```

router.js: If you can see i've commented the use of modules when call the router because I wasn't able to load modules with requirejs. So, I just call directly the controller defined in each module.

```
define(["app",
    "backbone"],
function (GB) {
   var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "home": "initializeHome",
        "aboutus": "initializeAbout",
        "services-container": "initializeServices",
        "signup": "initializeSignup"
    },
    initializeHome: function () {
        GB.Home.Controllers.Overview.show();
        //require(["home/home.module"], function () {
        //    GB.routers.Home = new HomeRouter();
        //});
    },
    initializeAbout: function () {
        GB.About.Controllers.Overview.show();
        //require(["aboutus/aboutus.module"], function () {
        //    GB.routers.About = new AboutRouter("aboutus", this.options);
        //});
    },
    initializeServices: function () {
        console.log("services");
        //require(["home/home.module"], function () {
        //    GB.routers.Home = new HomeRouter();
        //});
    },
    initializeSignup: function () {
        console.log("signup");
        GB.Signup.Controllers.Overview.show();
    }
  });

   return router;
 });
```

home.module.js

```
define(["app", "home/home.controller"], function (GB, controller) {
var module = {};
module.Controllers = {
    Overview: controller
}

GB.Home = module;

return GB.Home;
```

});

home.controller.js

```
define(["app", "modules/home/overview"], function (GB, HomeLayout) {
return {
    show: function () {
        var layout = new HomeLayout();
        GB.regions.main.show(layout);
    }
}
});
```

home.overview.js

```
 define([
  "marionette",
  "text!modules/home/home.html",
  "modules/home/slider/slider.view",
  "modules/home/services/services.view",
 ],
function (Marionette, Template, SliderView, ServicesView) {
    var view = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        template: Template,
        regions: {
            slider: "#banner",
            services: "#services-container"
        },
        onRender: function () {
            var sliderView = new SliderView();
            this.slider.show(sliderView);

            var servicesView = new ServicesView();
            this.services.show(servicesView);
        }
    });
    return view;
});
```

slider.view.js: This View depends on thempunch.revolution plugin which is loaded in the App.js

```
define(["marionette", "text!modules/home/slider/slider.html"],
function (Marionette, SliderTemplate) {
    var view = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        className: "slideshow",
        tagName: "div",
        template: SliderTemplate,
        onRender: function () {
            if (this.$el.length > 0) {
                this.$(".tp-bannertimer").show();

                this.initSlider();

            }
        },
        initSlider: function () {

            this.$(".slider-banner-fullwidth-big-height").show().revolution({
              ...

            });
        };

    return view;
});
```

I'd appreciate any help because I've worked with this problem since many time ago. Thanks

Comment: here too much code. Separate the question into several smaller ones. But first, I would say that you misunderstand the use of shim. It should be used if the library does not support AMD. There is no need shim for backbone and marionette. How you can know it? Try to found 'defne.amd' in required lib.

Comment: can you please post service.view and slider.view

Answer (score 0):

By chance are you trying Marionette v3 release candidate?  I believe the bundled version of the library is broken for requirejs.  But you can use 'marionette': '../lib/core/backbone.marionette', and then you'll also need to include backbone.babysitter and backbone.radio separately.